# Multiple values in decode Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, where-clause, decode

I have simple question but I cannot find the solution. I need:

```
WHERE
(tableABC.name = (DECODE (:p_type,'Morning', 'GOODMORNING',
                                  'Afternoon', 'GOODAFTERNOON',
                                  'Day', IN('GOODMORNING','GOODAFTERNOON'))
```

Unfortunately it does not work. I cannot use any other table because it is used in report and "Morning, Afternoon, Day" are imagined words (it should be user friendly). The seconds exist really in table but there are also many next values for this column (e.g.: 'GOODEVENING', 'GOODNIGHT'). 
I need select only two values from the particular column with many different values which will be selected under "Day" selection.

Thanks a lot,
D.

Comment: your question is not clear  .. update  ..and add  a proper data sample  .and the expected  result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't change the comparison condition from `=` to `IN` in the middle like that. You can achieve your goal by switching to just use simple Boolean logic:

```
WHERE (:p_type = 'Morning' AND tableABC.name = 'GOODMORNING')
   OR (:p_type = 'Afternoon' AND tableABC.name = 'GOODAFTERNOON')
   OR (:p_type = 'Day' AND tableABC.name IN ('GOODMORNING', 'GOODAFTERNOON'))
```

with an extra set of parentheses enclosing the whole thing if you have other conditions:

```
WHERE ((:p_type = 'Morning' AND tableABC.name = 'GOODMORNING')
    OR (:p_type = 'Afternoon' AND tableABC.name = 'GOODAFTERNOON')
    OR (:p_type = 'Day' AND tableABC.name IN ('GOODMORNING', 'GOODAFTERNOON')))
AND <something else>
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `decode()`.  Don't even use `case`.  Just express this as boolean logic:

```
WHERE (:p_type = 'Morning' AND tableABC.name = 'GOODMORNING') OR
      (:p_type = 'Afternoon' AND tableABC.name = 'GOODAFTERNOON') OR
      (:p_type = 'Day' AND tableABC.name IN ('GOODMORNING', 'GOODAFTERNOON'))
```